# Simplenavigation - How to create dynamic menu items?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create a dynamic menu with simple navigation.

The problem is that the menu only works on the show action that should show dynamic menu items. All other pages gives the error:

```
undefined method `model_name' for #<Class:0x9236118>
```

I have read this, but have not found any solution:

https://github.com/andi/simple-navigation/wiki/Dynamic-Navigation-Items

My navigation.rb:

```
sub_nav.item :virk, 'Virksomheder', virk_path, :link => {:style => 'font-weight:bolder;', :class => 'submini'} do |virknavn|
virknavn.item :virksom, @virksomhed.try(:name), url_for(@virksomhed), :highlights_on => /virksomheder\/[0-9]+/
end
```

I only want the virknavn menu items to be highlighted on:

```
/virksomheder/:some virksomhed name
```

My virksomhed controller:

```
  def index
    @virksomheds = Virksomhed.all
    render :layout => 'page'
  end

  # GET /webhosts/1
  # GET /webhosts/1.xml
  def show
    @virksomhed = Virksomhed.find(params[:id])
    render :layout => 'page'
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to figure out that I just could set a if statement in the navigation.rb:

```
if params[:id].blank?
params[:id] = Virksomhed.first.id
end
@virksomhed = Virksomhed.find(params[:id])
if @virksomhed.blank?
@virksomhed = Virksomhed.first
end
```

And it did the magick.